# Fanout feature classes in different feature datasets

Tags: arcgis-pro, fme-form, data-interoperability

I am using ArcGIS Pro 2.9 with the Data Interoperability Extension. I try to fan out different feature classes with FME. Using the "fanout dataset"-function, I manage to create multiple geodatabases. However, I want to have my data within one geodatabase in multiple feature datasets.

Is this even possible using FME, and if so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you are trying to use the same feature class name in more than one feature dataset within the same geodatabase.

That is not permissible with the geodatabase format.

Every feature class name within a geodatabase must be unique even if you try to place them in different feature datasets.

The restriction is documented at [Define feature class properties](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/help/data/geodatabases/overview/defining-feature-class-properties.htm).